# cmd.exe and adb command

Tags: c#, .net, process, adb, command-line-arguments

Hello I have some issue with cmd command via c#
for example I do manually commands in cmd.exe

```
//command1 to pick directory
cd C:\Users\NewSystem\source\repos
//command2 command to send file to emulator
adb -s emulator-5554 push Debug\funnels\01\01.mp4 /sdcard/Download
```

code I test in C# is and it doesnt work properly, exactly not send nothing to android emulator

```
Process cmd = new Process();
            cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            cmd.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Users\NewSystem\source\repos\";
            cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
            cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            cmd.Start();

            cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("adb -s emulator-5554 push Debug\funnels\01\01.mp4 /sdcard/Download");
            cmd.StandardInput.Flush();
            cmd.StandardInput.Close();
            cmd.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 1):

To start [`cmd.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd) and have it execute a command you need to pass `/c` (execute command and exit) or `/k` (execute command and remain)...

```
cmd /c adb -s emulator-5554 push Debug\funnels\01\01.mp4 /sdcard/Download
```

You don't need to have `cmd.exe` start `adb.exe`, though; just start `adb.exe` directly.

As for your C# code, [`StandardInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.standardinput) is for writing to a process's [`stdin` stream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_(stdin)), which is not what you want.  The way to pass command line arguments is using the [`ArgumentList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.argumentlist) (.NET (Core) 2.1+) or [`Arguments`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments) (all .NET Framework/Core versions) properties of [`ProcessStartInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo)...

```cs
// Dispose cmd when finished
using (Process cmd = new Process())
{
    // The full executable path is required if its directory is not in %PATH%
    cmd.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\NewSystem\source\repos\adb.exe";
    cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = @"-s emulator-5554 push ""Debug\funnels\01\01.mp4"" ""/sdcard/Download""";
    cmd.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Users\NewSystem\source\repos\";
    cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

    cmd.Start();
    cmd.WaitForExit();
}
```

I set `Arguments` to a [verbatim string](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/#regular-and-verbatim-string-literals) with the last two arguments quoted just to show how you would do so if either path contain spaces.